# missing ) after argument list, where do i put it this time?

Tags: javascript

```
if (typeof scriptLoadedMeowPuff === "undefined") {
var scriptLoadedMeowPuff = true;
var MTYPEWON = 0;

// when a message is recieved in chat...
MPP.client.on("a", (msg) => {
        if (msg.a.indexOf(MPP.client.getOwnParticipant().name + "First person ") !== -1 && msg.p._id === ("903bcaadc5c62dbf197798a0")) {
        MPP.chat.send("msg.p.a".split("First person to type this wins: "))
        }
    }
};
    console.log("%c You already pasted the script, " + MPP.client.getOwnParticipant().name + "!\n\n Refresh and paste the code again to see any changes.", "background: #000; color: #ff3333");
};
```

Comment: Just match your brackets and parentheses: gradually delete the statements that have matched parentheses and you end up with `if () { MPP.client.on("a", () => {} }; };`; and that’s where the errors are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work better for you:

```
if (typeof scriptLoadedMeowPuff === "undefined") {
var scriptLoadedMeowPuff = true;
var MTYPEWON = 0;

// when a message is recieved in chat...
MPP.client.on("a", (msg) => {
        if (msg.a.indexOf(MPP.client.getOwnParticipant().name + "First person ") !== -1 && msg.p._id === ("903bcaadc5c62dbf197798a0")) {
        MPP.chat.send("msg.p.a".split("First person to type this wins: "));
        }
    }
);
    console.log("%c You already pasted the script, " + MPP.client.getOwnParticipant().name + "!\n\n Refresh and paste the code again to see any changes.", "background: #000; color: #ff3333");
}
```

**EDIT** Oh, Frayne got there first, ah well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `MPP.client.on(`, you start with `(` but end with `}`, And no need to use the statement after a if condition, you did this in you parent if condition.

```
if (typeof scriptLoadedMeowPuff === "undefined") {
  var scriptLoadedMeowPuff = true;
  var MTYPEWON = 0;

  // when a message is recieved in chat...
  MPP.client.on("a", (msg) => {
    if (msg.a.indexOf(MPP.client.getOwnParticipant().name + "First person ") !== -1 && msg.p._id === ("903bcaadc5c62dbf197798a0")) {
      MPP.chat.send("msg.p.a".split("First person to type this wins: "));
    }
  });
  console.log("%c You already pasted the script, " + MPP.client.getOwnParticipant().name + "!\n\n Refresh and paste the code again to see any changes.", "background: #000; color: #ff3333");
}
```